# Steps to follow for correspondence analysis when each brand is not shown to every respondent

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, multidimensional-scaling, correspondence-analysis

I want to understand the steps followed for **correspondence analysis when each brand is not shown to every respondent**. Till now I used to assign a number (proportion) to each brand for each attribute and this **proportion is calculated as follows =** 
**(No. of time respondents have selected particular brand for particular attribute / Total no. of respondents to whom particular brand is shown)**. I used this technique to give weight to a brand according to no. of times it is shown to respondents.

I have doubt whether this methodology is correct as correspondence can be applied on counts only not on proportion and if this method is wrong then what should I do to deal with this issue.

Comment: I haven't time to check it, but your idea seems justifiable. I think that you may go on with this "weighting". You may multiply the proportions obtained by the total number of respondents, if you want to do the analysis strictly on counts.

Comment: but total respondents will vary with different brands...